# returning promise and resolving multiple await inside it

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, promise

So I have to create a function:

```
const someData = await this.someservice.generateData();
```

Now,inside `generateData()`:

```
generateData(){
  try{
    const d1= await this.someServerCall();
    const d2 = await this.someServerCall2();
    
    // resolve promise with this data
    return { 
        obj1: d1,
        obj2: d2
    }
  } catch(e){
     // reject Promise
  }

}
```

I unable to understand how to wrap it inside:

```
return new Promise(function (resolveFunc, rejectFunc) {
   resolveFunc(some_data)
   rejectFunc(error);
}
```

so that I get data by calling `await this.someservice.generateData();` When I put the serverCalls inside `Promise`, I get  `Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments.t`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to declare generateData as an async function.

```
async generateData(){
  try{
    const d1= await this.someServerCall();
    const d2 = await this.someServerCall2();
    
    // resolve promise with this data
    return { 
        obj1: d1,
        obj2: d2
    }
  } catch(e){
     // reject Promise
  }
```

After your that are free to call it with await.